# disable jscrollpane in specfic div

Tags: child-theme

I installed the library jscrollpane , and its working fine 
but i need to disable it in the #content that is in frontpage template 
    
    //

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //tells WP to recognize the $ variable

//paste your jquery code here
$('#content').jScrollPane();

}); //end document ready functions

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

http://www.integritycorp.org/study/

i just want to disable in frontpage but working on the rest of the theme 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work-

```
$('#content').not('body.home #content').jScrollPane();
```

Comment: @RashaNourEldin then mark the question as _answered_. Click on the checkmark on the left of this question. It looks like this: ✔

Comment: i dont know how ?

Comment: @RashaNourEldin Mr. toscho exscribed it _exactly_ in his comment ↑ above. Please read it again.

Comment: jscrollpane is not working anymore :(